# How to provide a contextual filter with an OR conjunction to a view?

Tags: 8, entities, views

I have users that can be associated with a single node of type foo. The node has a list of users that are associated with it. I populate the entity reference fields in the content type with a view, which filters users that aren't associated with foo `(user has no foo)`.

What I need to happen is that I need this view to also grab users that are associated with the specific node that I'm looking at, so when I try to add new users to the foo content type, the users that were associated with it beforehand remain associated with it `(user has no foo OR user's foo id equals current foo id)`. The problem is that the first filter is a normal filter, the second is a contextual filter. How can I, programmatically or otherwise, get the views to grab the users I need with those conditions?

**Edit:** Unfortunately, the views-related hooks aren't called when populating an Entity Reference, which makes things like `hook_views_query_alter` not a solution. So a more accurate question would be: *how can I get the entity reference to grab the users I need with the given conditions?*

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use **hook_views_query_alter** and then you could add your **OR** condition.

```
function hook_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
  if ($view->id() == 'machine_name_of_your_view' ) {
   //$query->where contains the filter conditions 
   //i.e. 'Where' part of the query where you could add yours.
   var_dump($query->where);die;
  }
}
```

[more from drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.2.x)

Comment: It would seem that using a view as an entity reference source doesn't cause hook_views_query_alter to be called. I've edited the question to reflect this.